# Wrapping up a method with ruby-progressbar gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, progress-bar

I am trying to use [ruby-progressbar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar) gem with [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) gem

My aim is to capture the dynamic progress bar during the git clone so that i can get the progress bar for this git clone

I am trying to use in this way

```
 def my_method
  p = ProgressBar.create(:format => '%a %B %p%% %t')
  Git.clone('git://github.com/ankit8898/rubymotion-inspect.git','my_repo',:path => '.') do
    p.increment
   end
 end
```

I am not able to get the progress bar as i expect it.

Anything wrong with the way i have initialized Progress bar ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

`Git.clone` (https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/blob/master/lib/git.rb#L87) doesn't expect a block. So the block you pass is simply ignored.

I don't see how this is possible, short of modifying `ruby-git` gem to enable progress notifications.

Comment: hmm, okay so forget about if i use ruby-git gem and i use normal `git clone git://github.com/ankit8898/rubymotion-inspect.git` . How can i still find the progressbar of clone.  My main aim to catch progress bar either by using ruby-git gem or simple git clone.

Comment: Try reading and interpreting output of this shell command. Maybe you'll be lucky.

Comment: well, that's a backup plan. :)  But still isn't there any other way to use git clone with progressbar gem.  Since i am interested in seeing the actually progressbar with git clone.

Answer (score 1):

The `Git` library adds `2>&1` to all the commands. So your clone command ends up being executed like:

```
git clone ... 2>&1
```

Which ends up suppressing all output. All you need to do is override a single method called `run_command` in `Git::Lib`, and remove that `2>&1`. You can try this in `irb`:

```
class Git::Lib
  class << self
    attr_accessor :verbose
  end

  def run_command(git_cmd, &block)
    git_cmd = git_cmd.gsub("2>&1", "").chomp if self.class.verbose
    if block_given?
      IO.popen(git_cmd, &block)
    else
      `#{git_cmd}`.chomp
    end
  end
end
```

I've defined an extra `verbose` attribute. So whenever you need the actual git outputs, just set `Git::Lib.verbose = true` and run `Git.clone` or any other command, and the actual outputs will be printed.

What this will do is, once you set `Git::Lib.verbose = true` and then call `Git.clone`, it will display the git progress bar like this:

```
Cloning into 'rapidftr-addon-cpims'...
remote: Counting objects: 207, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (108/108), done.
remote: Total 207 (delta 95), reused 201 (delta 90)
Receiving objects: 50% (105/207), 83.10 KiB | 112 KiB/s...
# ^^ The above line is git's progress bar, it will keep updating
```

It may not show the progress bar in the specific format that you expect, but it will still show dynamic updates as the download happens.

Edit: Added sample outputs

Comment: He still needs to parse and interpret the output. I don't think he's interested in raw `git clone` output.

Comment: From the question, I thought the overall objective was just to display the progress bar. I don't see the OP doing anything with the progress other than displaying it. So wouldn't it be easier to use the default progress bar output of git itself?

Comment: The command also prints other content, not only progress bar. Also the OP wants the bar in a specific format, as you can see.

Comment: @RDX, thanks for your reply.  But this is not something i am looking for.  I want to use the progress bar gem .  If you see the readme `https://github.com/peleteiro/progressbar` you will understand the output i want to get.  I don't want to get into the pain of parsing a git clone output and fetching the progress.

Comment: @AnkitG if you really want a custom progress bar, then there is no option but to parse that git clone output, since git has no other way to inform you of the progress.You could add a `grep Receiving objects` to the end of the patch, so that all the unnecessary output like `Counting objects`, `Compressing objects`, etc are removed and only git's progress bar is shown.